# Python, formatting re.findall() output

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to get to grips with regex in Python. I'm writing a very simple script to scrape emails off a given URL.

```
import re
from urllib.request import *


url = input("Please insert the URL you wish to scrape> ")

page = urlopen(url)

content = page.read()

email_string = b'[a-z0-9_. A-Z]*@[a-z0-9_. A-Z]*.[a-zA-Z]'

emails_in_page = re.findall(email_string, content)

print("Here are the emails found: ")

for email in emails_in_page:
    print(email)
```

re.findall() returns a list, and when the program prints out the emails, the "b" from the regex string is included in the output, like this:

```
b'email1@email.com'
b'email2@email.com'
...
```

How can I have a clean list of emails printed out? (ie: `email1@email.com`)

Comment: Why do you reject `+` signs in the local part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing `bytes` objects. Decode them to strings:

```
encoding = page.headers.get_param('charset')
if encoding is None:
    encoding = 'utf8'  # sensible default

for email in emails_in_page:
    print(email.decode(encoding))
```

or decode the HTML page you retrieved:

```
encoding = page.headers.get_param('charset')
if encoding is None:
    encoding = 'utf8'  # sensible default

content = page.read().decode(encoding)
```

and use a unicode string regular expression:

```
email_string = '[a-z0-9_. A-Z]*@[a-z0-9_. A-Z]*.[a-zA-Z]'
```

Many webpages do not send a proper charset parameter in the content-type header, or set it wrong, so even the 'sensible default' can be wrong from time to time.

A HTML parsing library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) would do a better job of codec detection still, it includes some more heuristics to make an educated guess:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), from_encoding=page.headers.get_param('charset'))
for textelem in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(email_string)):
    print(textelem)
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn, when I run your code (decoding the byte objects, not the HTML), I get this:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_scraper.py", line 11, in <module>
    encoding = page.headers.getparam('charset')
AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getparam'